# python requests.get() InvalidSchema error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm incredibly new to python, and i'm trying to write something to get the first result returned from Google' "I'm feeling lucky" button. I have a list of 100 items I need it to get urls for. Here's what i have:

```
import requests

with open('2012.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for i in range(0, 100):
    temp1 = "r'http://www.google.com/search?q=\""
    temp2 = "\"&btnI'"
    temp3 = lines[i]
    temp3 = temp3[:-1]
    temp4 = temp1+temp3+temp2
    print temp4
    var = requests.get(temp4)
    print var.url
```

Now if I print the value in `temp4` and paste it into `requests.get()`, it works as I want it to. However, I get error's every time I try to pass `temp4` in, instead of a hard-coded string.

Comment: Just edited the Q to make the code readable -- highlight it and click the icon looking a bit like `{}` ("code block" I think it says if you hover).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, I guess you're getting:

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'r'http://www.google.com/search?q="foo"&btnI''
```

(except with something else in lieu of `foo`:-) -- please post exceptions as part of your Q, why make us guess or need to reproduce?!

The problem is obviously that leading `r'` which does indeed make the string into an invalid schema (the trailing `'` doesn't help either).

So, try instead something like:

```
temp1 = 'http://www.google.com/search?q="'
temp2 = '"&btnI'
```

and things should go better... specifically, when I do that (still with `'foo'` in lieu of a real `temp3`), I get

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar
```

which seems to make sense as the top search result for "foo"!-)